# Wiring diagram for USB-C to USB-A cable?

Tags: usb, wiring, cables, diagram, usb-c

I make USB cables (USB-A to Mini or Micro primarily), but don't have any experience with USB-C. I would like to create a cable that has a USB-A (2.0) connector on one end, and a USB-C connector on the other (mainly for connecting keyboards to CPUs, and charging devices). How do I wire this properly (typically I use a 4-core 28AGW cable)? Thanks in advance for any help, please let me know if I need to clarify further!

Comment: Which side of type A? Plug or socket?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to buy such a cable, or buy a USB c to a male and get an adapter which changes the gender of the connector. Saves the effort of soldering the tiny pins on the USB c connector.

Comment: @Apphone Your proposed edit seems to be answering the question. If so, please use the **Your Answer** field below to post your answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [USB 3.1 specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/) spells out exactly how to make this, and any other USB C -to- USB legacy cable. For a USB-A (2.0), the connection looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sbell! The spec is what I was looking for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @rockwell Glad I could help! If this answers your question, make sure to accept this as the correct answer

Comment: On the USB-C end...if I solder the A5 pin directly to the VBUS (instead of with a resistor), will that work if the connector has a resistor built into it?

Comment: @rockwell No, you really shouldn't. USB-C is reversible and the resistor on the CC line informs the slave device on how to route the signals correctly. The value of this resistor can also be changed to signal higher current capacity (which you probably shouldn't do). See here for more info: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001914B.pdf

Comment: Now it's USB 3.2

Comment: The "electro-mechanical definition and requirements for USB connectors and cables" have been removed from the USB 3.2 specification and can instead be found in the USB Type-C Cable and Connector
Specification (https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf) on page 79.