# Adapt existing usb-2 otg device to usb-c but use usb-2 mode

Tags: usb, usb-c, samd21

there are number of articles out there, like this one: http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slly017/slly017.pdf

But I'm not super confident in my abilities here so I'm wondering if someone could proof my schematic to make sure it's going to work. Will this schematic work (simply connecting d+ and d- to the microcontroller (samd21) d+ and d- pins and cc1/cc2 to the usbhost pin?

I should explain the reason: I want to be able to not look at the usb when I plug it in, usb-c is a better user experience but I don't need the speed or other things, just the reversible plug and I want it to conform to what is quickly becoming the new standard.

Another link showing the method of adapting usb-c to usb-a: [Wiring diagram for USB-C to USB-A cable?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323128/wiring-diagram-for-usb-c-to-usb-a-cable) As comments have indicated, you can't simply emulate usb2.0 otg with a pull down resister.

[image]

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001914B.pdf

[image]

Comment: The TI article clearly articulates what needs to be done to convert USB2 OTG device into Type-C OTG device. You have to use their TUSB32x product line. Why do you disregard the reputable manufacturer advice and try some kludge which won't work for many reasons and for many modes?

Comment: This question is unanswerable because you fail to specify what exactly you wish to connect to exactly what.  If you're willing to go non standard, why not add some sort of tactile orientation hint to the outside of the plug's overmold?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the question is fully answerable with the answer NO, this kludge won't work. The explanation, however, might need some space and a need an excursion into what u-AB OTG is, and how different the Type-C role swapping is.

Comment: @Ale..chenski - it would for example work if it was merely a custom non-standard connector hack on USB 2.0 devices, especially if the role is fixed as part of that hack.

Comment: The title says "OTG". Do you want to maintain the OTG functionality, or not?

Comment: @Ale..chenski initially no, but I was curious about the option to do so.